# Color Output in MFC List issue

Tags: c++, mfc

This code is about the worm game. It is a problem to print the color of the `tail` section. The code is written so that the worm's head grows longer and longer each time it eats. And from head to tail, it goes from green to blue. where the initial values for `_GboxColor`, `_BboxColor`, and `Colornum` are 255, 0, and 1, respectively. The `Colornum` increases by one every time the worm eats its food. I'll put an example gif at the bottom of this questionnaire. As you can see in the gif, You can see that the third part of the body from the head of the worm turned blue for a moment as soon as the head ate. There seems to be no problem with the code, but I don't know why this is happening. How do I make the color a little softer?

```cpp
    // head
    int halfLength = 10;
    CBrush brush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    memDc.SelectObject(brush);
    memDc.Rectangle(_headPos.x - halfLength, _headPos.y - halfLength, _headPos.x + halfLength, _headPos.y + halfLength);
    
    // tail
    int bodyColorFig = 255 / Colornum;
    POSITION traversalNode = _boxes.GetHeadPosition();
    _GboxColor = 255;
    _BboxColor = 0;
    while (traversalNode != nullptr) {
        _bodyPos = _boxes.GetAt(traversalNode);
        _GboxColor -= bodyColorFig;
        _BboxColor += bodyColorFig;
        CBrush brush(RGB(0, _GboxColor, _BboxColor));
        memDc.SelectObject(brush);
        memDc.Rectangle(_bodyPos.x - halfLength, _bodyPos.y - halfLength, _bodyPos.x + halfLength, _bodyPos.y + halfLength);
        _boxes.GetNext(traversalNode);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a breakpoint to see the value of _GboxColor when drawing the 3rd segment. Maybe an overrun occurs (the RGB macro hides the fact that the color is just a 32-bit value). Maybe you should initialize _GboxColor and _BboxColor before the while loop, not after it.

Comment: I edited it, but the problem remains the same. I edited questions.

Comment: @Keastmin And what are the values of the variables when the 3rd segment turns blue?